# Old Version of Newtonsoft.JSon being Used in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, json.net, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an application where I have removed my references to the Newtonsoft.Json library and used instead Swashbuckle.ASpNetCore.Newtonsoft version 6.1.4.  When I run this locally everything works great.  Swagger loads, I am able to query my API with no issues and the world is a nice place.  I deploy this code to an Azure Server in Docker and where everything there was working great before, now I have problems.  Swagger will not load and my API doesn't work at all, because the application doesn't even start.  It would appear that something, somewhere is looking for Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0.0 because this is the error I get in the logs.

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue in the future, here is the solution in my case.  The Coverlet NuGet package was causing this error.  I removed the package and the problem went away.